# javascriptを使ってXMLを上から順番に解析したい。

Tags: javascript, xml

perlのXML::LibXML::Readerを使うと、XMLを、上から順番にノードを取得して解析できますが、javascript(あるいはjQueryなど)ではどのようにすればよいでしょうか？あるいは同様のことができるライブラリはあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

以前は E4Xというのがありました。今では非推奨です。

代わりに, DOMParser 使うと良いようです

参考:

- (MDN) [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

  - [XML のパースとシリアライズ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML)
- (Wikipedia) [ECMAScript for XML](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML)

サンプルに示されてるコード

```js
const xml = `<sales vendor="John">
    <item type="peas" price="4" quantity="6"/>
    <item type="carrot" price="3" quantity="10"/>
    <item type="chips" price="5" quantity="3"/>
</sales>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const sales = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml');
const items = Array.from(sales.getElementsByTagName("item"));
alert(items.find(item => item.getAttribute("type") === "carrot").getAttribute("quantity"));
alert(sales.getElementsByTagName("sales").item(0).getAttribute("vendor"));
items.forEach(item => alert(item.getAttribute("price")))
```